# SSH key pair in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

What is a way to pass a key in Terraform for an EC2 spin up?

```
variable "public_path" {

    default  = "D:\"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "app_keypair" {
  public_key = file(var.public_path)
  key_name   = "my_key"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "ami-12345678"
  instance_type = "t1.micro"
  key_name = aws_key_pair.app_keypair
  security_groups = [ "${aws_security_group.test_sg.id}" ]
}
```

Error:

> Invalid value for "path" parameter: failed to read D:".

Comment: You need to pass the path to a key file, right now you're only passing the path to a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash: `tree`

```
.
├── data
│   └── key
└── main.tf

1 directory, 2 files
```

Above is what my file system looks like. I'm not on windows. You were passing the directory and thinking that `key_name` means it would find the name of your key in that directory. But the fuction `file()` has no idea what `key_name` is. That is a value local to the `aws_key_pair` resource. So make sure you give the `file` fuction the full path to the file.

Look below for my code. You also passed `aws_key_pair.app_keypair` to your `aws_instance` resource. But that's an object that contains several properties. You need to specify which property you want to pass. In this case `aws_key_pair.app_keypair.key_name`. This will cause aws to stand up an EC2 and then look for a key pair with the name in your code. Then it associates them together.

```
provider aws {
    profile = "myprofile"
    region = "us-west-2"
}

variable "public_path" {
    default  = "./data/key"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "app_keypair" {
  public_key = file(var.public_path)
  key_name   = "somekeyname"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "ami-12345678"
  instance_type = "t1.micro"
  key_name = aws_key_pair.app_keypair.key_name
}
```

Here is my plan output. You can see the key is getting injected correctly. This is the same key in the terraform docs, so it's safe to put in here.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.web will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "web" {
      <...ommitted for stack overflow brevity...>
      + key_name                     = "somekeyname"
      <...ommitted for stack overflow brevity...>
    }

  # aws_key_pair.app_keypair will be created
  + resource "aws_key_pair" "app_keypair" {
      + arn         = (known after apply)
      + fingerprint = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + key_name    = "somekeyname"
      + key_pair_id = (known after apply)
      + public_key  = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQD3F6tyPEFEzV0LX3X8BsXdMsQz1x2cEikKDEY0aIj41qgxMCP/iteneqXSIFZBp5vizPvaoIR3Um9xK7PGoW8giupGn+EPuxIA4cDM4vzOqOkiMPhz5XK0whEjkVzTo4+S0puvDZuwIsdiW9mxhJc7tgBNL0cYlWSYVkz4G/fslNfRPW5mYAM49f4fhtxPb5ok4Q2Lg9dPKVHO/Bgeu5woMc7RY0p1ej6D4CKFE6lymSDJpW0YHX/wqE9+cfEauh7xZcG0q9t2ta6F6fmX0agvpFyZo8aFbXeUBr7osSCJNgvavWbM/06niWrOvYX2xwWdhXmXSrbX8ZbabVohBK41 email@example.com"
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```