# How can I add key_name to the resource of an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In [Terraform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraform_(software)), how can I specify an EC2 private/public key pair, when launching a new EC2 instance?

I am following *[Is `ubuntu` the default user for an Ubuntu image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73351709/is-ubuntu-the-default-user-for-an-ubuntu-image/73351869#73351869)* (now deleted) and *[SSH key pair in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999861/ssh-key-pair-in-terraform/64287520#64287520)* to add key_name to a resource in the following main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

variable "public_path" {
  default = "/path/to/MyKeyPair.pem"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "app_keypair" {
  public_key = file(var.public_path)
  key_name   = "somekeyname"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-052efd3df9dad4825"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-xxxxx"]
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.app_keypair.key_name

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }
}
```

but

```
terraform apply
```

Output:

```
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_key_pair.app_keypair: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error importing EC2 Key Pair (somekeyname): InvalidParameterValue: Value for parameter PublicKeyMaterial is invalid. Length exceeds maximum of 2048.
│       status code: 400, request id: 72425610-202e-42ce-98b4-a8dce5fef694
│
│   with aws_key_pair.app_keypair,
│   on main.tf line 21, in resource "aws_key_pair" "app_keypair":
│   21: resource "aws_key_pair" "app_keypair" {
│
```

Why is it and what can I do about it?

Comment: Are you sure that you provided the path to the public and not private key? If you are using the public one, you will need to recreate it to have the required length it seems.

Comment: What is unclear about "Value for parameter PublicKeyMaterial is invalid. Length exceeds maximum of 2048."? The error references the key material which you did not say anything about in your post. Your path is incorrect and / or you created an incompatible key.

Comment: @MarkoE the file was created by `aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name MyKeyPair --query 'KeyMaterial' --output text > MyKeyPair.pem`. It stores the private key, and the public key is not stored locally, if I am correct. Do I need to provide a pathname of a file storing a public key in the .tf file?

Comment: @luk2302  `/path/to/MyKeyPair.pem` is very short. what is not clear about my question?

Comment: Ok, not sure what that AWD CLI command does, but it says in the argument you need the public key. The public key is what is stored on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

See the "NOTE:" at the bottom of the [aws_key_pair](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/key_pair#import) documentation.

> The AWS API does not include the public key in the response, so terraform apply will attempt to replace the key pair. There is currently no supported workaround for this limitation.

And I can tell by your comment that you know the `create-key-pair` output key material is the private key, which is correct and can be verified in the [Create key pairs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-key-pairs.html) documentation.

> Use the create-key-pair command as follows to generate the key pair and to save the private key to a .pem file.

So if you want to create a key locally and use this terrform resource, you'll need to use a method that leaves you with public key material, like openssh. I'd recommend following the [Create a key pair using a third-party tool and import the public key to Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws) section, if you intend to do so.